# Long Exact sequence of Relative Homotopy Groups: examples and applications

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm going to make a talk around higher homotopy groups, and the long exact sequence of relative homotopy groups. I would like to show some nice examples and applications of this theorem after the proof, can someone show/link me some of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are  applications 
in the book partially titled [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/nonab-a-t.html) (pdf available there) and lots of history and intuition. 
The lower dimensional case

$$\partial: \pi_2(X,A,x) \to \pi_1(A,x)$$

has good applications to group theory (identities among relations).

Various presentations on my  [preprint page](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/brownpr.html) (e.g. the Galway talk) give other relations with  algebraic topology.

Comment: It is not easy to see where the applications are. It would help if you could describe one here, I think.

Comment: @Mike Miller: I'll see what I can cook up; we wrote 35.  (R. Brown and  J. HUEBSCHMANN), ``Identities among relations'', in
_Low  dimensional topology_, London Math. Soc. Lecture Note
Series 48 (ed. R.  Brown and T.L. Thickstun, Cambridge University
Press, 1982), pp.  153-202.a long time ago! Some of this is in Section 3.1 of the above book.